# LINQ query doesn't return the single value

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have this query and I want to return a single value which is the I.Id and I have a parameter which is filled with an Id that is sent from a Controller to the Dao(Where the Linq query is nested).
The problem is, that this query isn't just returning a value, is returning every fields in the table that this query produces and I just want the Id.

This is the query:

```
public InscriptionDetail GetInscriptionIdByPersonId(int id)
        {
            using (var db = new HIQTrainingEntities())
            {
                var inscription =
                        from i in db.Inscriptions
                        join c in db.Certifications on i.PersonId equals c.PersonId
                        where i.PersonId == id
                        select new InscriptionDetail
                        {
                            Id = i.Id,
                        }; 
                return inscription.FirstOrDefault();
                 }
        }
```

Can someone help me with this query ? 
What's wrong ?

Comment: the definition of `InscriptionDetail` is what?

Comment: Is the SQL query itself returning all columns in the table? Or is the method returning an `InscriptionDetail` with properties other than `Id` also populated? Or is it returning an `InscriptionDetail` with fields other than `Id` showing default values (e.g. 0 for ints, null for string, etc)?

Comment: Because  InscriptionDetail is the expected return type from the method.

Comment: An 'InsciptionDetail' object is returned from the method. If you want to access the id you can do InscriptionDetail.Id.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your return type is of `InscriptionDetail`. If it is only the int id you need to return, why not change to the following?

```cs
public int GetInscriptionIdByPersonId(int personId)
{
    using (var db = new HIQTrainingEntities())
    {
        var inscription =
            from i in db.Inscriptions
            join c in db.Certifications on i.PersonId equals c.PersonId
            where i.PersonId == personId
            select i.Id;
        return inscription.FirstOrDefault();
     }
 }
```